# SortBy linq not working

Tags: angular, linq, typescript

I am trying to sort the result of an API using LINQ but it not working

I am expecting sorted rows in the grid based on hostname, but I am getting unsorted one.

> this.addservers = res.sortBy(x=> x.hostname);

```
 getAddServer() {
        this.AddServerService.getAddServer()
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.addservers = res.sortBy(x=> x.hostname);               

                this.total = this.addservers.length;
            });

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I think following should work.

this.addservers = res.sort(
function (x, y) {
    return  x.hostname > y.hostname? 1 : 0;
}
);
```